# Need to force close the "Phone" (Dialer) app manually

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, phone-app, lg, lg-optimus-l5

I have `LG E612` (`Jelly bean 4.1.2`).

My problem is, my **`phone` (`dialer`) app** will not close automatically when I press "**Back**" from `dialer` to `Home screen`.

`Phone app` is still running in background, and I need to close it through a `task killer`.

Is this a normal behavior with all android phones? If not, is there any settings for this?

Comment: Leave the memory management to the OS. It depends on the version (4.1.2 in your case) the OEM (LG) and the particular dialer app (not sure what one you have). As a rule task killers degrade performance, and the app being in memory has no impact on your battery or performance. I'd say leave it be. It's running on 4.4.2 for me on a custom ROM and on Stock on the Neuxus.

Comment: Thanks @RossC , But in my case, (using pre-installed dialer app), i think it eats more battery... If i force close it (using pre-installed app manager), I can clearly see increase in battery life and performance! Also, I can receive calls without any problem even if i force close it!

Comment: Yeah the dialer app doesn't dictate whether you can receive calls, there's a mechanism for that elsewhere that then calls the Dialer. But you'd need to check the battery stats to see if it actually is eating battery, and if it is then it is misbehaving somehow. Mine does show as 'running' but like any other app in the background the battery use is negligible / zero. Has you dialer a huge amount of cache or data it is trying to sort or something maybe? I'm at a bit of a loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @[RossC](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/40036/rossc), for your comments.

Adding this as answer:

> Leave the memory management to the OS. It depends on the version
>   (4.1.2 in your case), the OEM (LG) and the particular dialer app. As a
>   rule, task killers degrade performance, and the app being in memory
>   has no impact on your battery or performance. I'd say leave it be.